# How do I send a Zebra GX420d printer to print with the Dart, or how do I configure Android's IP?

Tags: android, printing, zebra-printers

Good afternoon and thank you for stopping to read this message.
My problem is that my team and I made an application with Flutter sided with a webapp with Spring, but in this case what matters is the app, since i'll be sent to print from a Zebra GX420d wired thermal printer. The printer is connected via Ethernet to a router and the Android phone is also connected to the same router, but wirelessly. The idea is to connect several printers to the same router and for each phone to be connected to its corresponding printer, so that each phone only sends printing to a single printer IP. Is there a Dart library that I can use to specify the code to which IP of which printer it should be sent? Or how can I configure each Android phone to only send printing to one IP of the printer and have it as default? I have tried searching for Zebra drivers and drivers for that printer model on Android and doing the setup, but have not found. What I can do? Sorry for so much text and I really appreciate the fact that I have read everything to understand my problem and I will be much more grateful if you could help me.
Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

How you can do this depends on whatever print service drivers app you have installed on the phone. A basic feature of any printer management software is to allow you to setup a network printer by IP.